# Axis2 wsdl2java code on apache karaf

Tags: java, web-services, maven, apache-axis, apache-karaf

My goal is to call a third party web service. So I generated the java classes from the wsdl using axis2 wsdl2java and adb data binding.

I'm calling the web service using these generated classes which works fine.

Now I want do do this in a bundle which is deployed on the osgi container apache karaf. I am building the bundle using the maven-bundle-plugin. Here I got the problem that karaf needs all those requirements of axis2 (axiom, mime4j, commons-fileupload,etc etc).

Is there any good solution to get axis2 to work on karaf besides deploying all those dependencies as bundles on karaf (because these are quite a lot)?

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>AxWebServiceCall</groupId>
<artifactId>AxWebServiceCall</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<name>Ax WebService calls</name>
<url></url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>AxWebServiceCall</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Private-Package>AxWebServiceCall.*</Private-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>com.foo.myservice</packageName>
                        <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/wsdl/axservice.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

And how I call the WebService

```
RoutingServiceStub stub = new RoutingServiceStub(
            "http://some.url");

PaygateServiceHBXProcessRequest paygateRequest = new PaygateServiceHBXProcessRequest();

PaygateContractHBX contract = new PaygateContractHBX();
contract.setLength(Integer.valueOf(data.get("length").toString()));
contract.setData(data.get("encrypted_data").toString());
paygateRequest.set_paygateContract(contract);

CallContextE context = new CallContextE();
CallContext paygateContext = new CallContext();
paygateContext.setCompany("HB2C");
context.setCallContext(paygateContext);

PaygateServiceHBXProcessResponse response = stub.process(
            paygateRequest, context);

AusfuehrungErgebnis response2 = response.getResponse();
```

And the error I get in the karaf logs

```
[...]Unable to resolve 994.0: missing requirement [994.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.axiom.om)[...]
```

As I said I can solve this by deploying the axiom bundle but then it needs the next dependency which I could also deploy and so on...But as I said I want this to work without deploying numerous bundles manually.

Comment: May I inquire why you are using axis2 to generate the web client? If you are doing Web Services in Karaf, it is highly recommended to use CXF. I noticed that CXF was already listed in your Maven dependencies.

Can you substitute cxf-codegen-plugin (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) for axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin ?

Comment: I could but I thought axis2 is more convenient for calling a webservice because it also generates a stub to call the service. Afaik with cxf I still have to do many things to call the service don't I?

Comment: @Milla Do you have any experience deploying Axis2 based SOAP service in apache karaf? Any article/reference would be of great help to me!

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is don't use Axis2 on karaf - too many dependencies. Just use The Java standard JAX-WS to call the SOAP service. This is what I did it works just fine and has - because it is in the standard - no dependencies.